# How to write a script to run different application

Tags: bash, scripts

I am very new to linux platform.

Looking for a script file to call different application start up file located in different location and needs to be run in different terminals.

For example :

i have two .sh file like a.sh and b.sh in different locations.

Now need a script file to run these .sh file. when i run that script it should be open two terminals . In the first terminal a.sh should be  called and b.sh file should be run on second terminal .

Thanks in advance for help.

Regards,
Raghu

Answer (score 2):

That is quite simple. Write a script something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e /bin/bash /path/to/script_1.sh &
xterm -e /bin/bash /path/to/script_2.sh &
```

The `-e` option means "execute". The argument after it is the command to execute (here it is /bin/bash) and the next option is the argument for the command (here the name of the script-file). `&` means that the xterm-commands are running in background. If you remove the first `&`, it will run the first script completely and afterwards it will start the next command, but as I understood your question you want to run them simultaneously, so leave the `&` there.

You can also use the standard terminal instead of xterm, but this depends on the distribution and desktop you use. For example in gnome it would be `gnome-terminal -x`, but it should not make any difference when using xterm.

Hope this helps.

Greatings, Darth Ravage

Comment: I thought it was `gnome-terminal -e` *(`-x` seems to work as well, but `-e` appears in the `--help` page)*... Also, with gnome-terminal, you can get it to hold the terminal open *(in preferences, under 'Title & Command')*, so you can see the output when the scripts exits. Also, if the scripts being called have the shebang line `#!/bin/bash`, you shouldn't need to prefix the command `/bin/bash` (or `bash`)

Comment: You're perfectly right with the `-e`. My mistake. I wrote `/bin/bash` just for the sake of completeness, but as you said it is perfectly possible to just write `bash`. Thanks for the constructive criticism.